# PHP is_null: Only boolean true and false, not even null?

Tags: php, boolean, isnull

Following up on this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461146/php-filter-var-how-to-make-sure-the-user-provides-correct-data-types-true-or), I decided to accept boolean true and false only, and **not** even `null` from the input by other developer/ user.

```
$default = array(
    "category_id"   =>  null,
    "category"      =>  false,
    "randomise"     =>  false
);

$config = array(
    "category_id"   =>  17,
    "randomise"     =>  false, 
    "category"      =>  null
);

function process_array($default,$config)
{
    # Set empty arrays for error & items.
    $error = array();
    $items = array();

    # Loop the array.
    foreach($default as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_bool($default[$key]) && isset($config[$key])) 
        {
            if ($config[$key] === null) $error[] = '"'. $key.'" cannot be null.';

            # Make sure that the value of the key is a boolean.
            if (!is_bool($config[$key])) 
            {
                $error[] = '"'. $key.'" can be boolean only.';
            }

        }

            if(isset($config[$key]) && !is_array($value))
            {
                $items[$key] = $config[$key];
            }
            elseif(isset($config[$key]) && is_array($value))
            {
                $items[$key] = array_merge($default[$key], $config[$key]);
            }
            else
            {
                $items[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        # Give a key to the error array.
        $error = array("error" => $error);

        # Merge the processed array with error array.
        # Return the result.
        return array_merge($items,$error);
}

print_r(process_array($default,$config));
```

but result I get is,

```
Array
(
    [category_id] => 17
    [category] => 
    [randomise] => 
    [error] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

the result I am after,

```
Array
(
    [category_id] => 17
    [category] => 
    [randomise] => 
    [error] => Array
        (
         [0] => "category" cannot be null.
        )

)
```

So I thought this line below should work, but I don't understand why it doesn't. I tried to use `is_null` but still not working. Any idea what have I done wrong and how can I fix this?

```
if ($config[$key] === null) $error[] = '"'. $key.'" cannot be null.';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset($config[$key])` returns false if the value is null. use `array_key_exists` (http://php.net/manual/function.array-key-exists.php) instead.

Answer (score 3):

I believe a `null` value will not pass the `isset()` test in `if (is_bool($default[$key]) && isset($config[$key]))`, so it's skipping over the whole block.

You'll need to refactor a bit to solve this I think. Maybe take the isset out of that if and move it to the null test?

`if (!isset($config[$key]) || is_null($config[$key])) $error[] = '"'. $key.'" cannot be null.';`

Comment: Thank you Bulk, I took Jordy's answer which works perfectly! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`null` wont pass the `is_bool` check either... as far as I'm aware - when it comes to `if statements` - best to be as simple as possible:

```
if (is_null($default[$key]))
{
  $error[] = '"'. $key.'" cannot be null.';
}
else if (!is_bool($default[$key])) 
{
  $error[] = '"'. $key.'" can be boolean only.';
}
```

As another poster has stated, it would also be best to wrap the above in an `array_key_exists` to avoid illegal offset warnings. Tbh, for a point of simplicity do you really need both of these checks? Specifying that `key` can only be a boolean should be adequate.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination, pebbl.